# How to update a field null in mongoDb with python

Tags: python, mongodb

I want to update a field in my MongoDB collection as `null`. Is it possible to do it using Python? The below code is what I tried. I got this exception:

> bson.errors.InvalidDocument: documents must have only string keys, key was None

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
client = MongoClient('localhost:27017')
db = client.data
address = None
db.employee.update({'email':"xxx@xxx.xom"},{$set:
{'address':address}})
```

Answer (score 1):

Python has notion of "None/NULL" to represent null values. But it is not same in MongoDB.

MongoDB doesn't recognize `None` as `NULL` value.  Hence you should either use `null` or empty string `""`